# Sharepoint disposable objects in HttpContext.Current.Items

Tags: sharepoint, dispose

There are a lot of solutions to my actual problem and I will not go into details here.
I'm not quite sure on one issue though.

If I was supposedely storing a SPWeb object instance in HttpContext.Current.Items... would it automatically be disposed at the end of the request (because SharePoint has some built-in mechanisms to dispose such objects) or do I need to dispose the objects myself using a custom HttpModule or global.asax?

I guess there's no magic and I have to do it myself, right?
I was wondering because of course SharePoint does basically the same... (HttpContext.Current.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"]...)

Answer (score 0):

You can read best practices about disposing SPWeb object [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557362.aspx). There are a lot of other articles on same subject.
In short:

1. If you create SPWeb object yourself (meaning not using
   SPContext.Current) you need to dispose it.
2. Dispose SPWeb object as soon as you do not need it.

From my experience caching SharePoint object is not a good way to go (even in request context) because it could lead to memory leaks.

Comment: I know all of that. That's why I asked if there's some kind of clean up routine that disposes of all objects within HttpContext.Current.Items - as I said SP is using that itself and obviously needs to clean that up somewhere.

Comment: Maybe it stores SPContext.Current information there. But i do not know how it cleans it up and i wouldn't count on it. In my opinion the best way is to clean up manually. You can of course try to find implementation details using Reflector but it can take a lot of time.